# Failing to Connect to Socket From Client Side

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to program a simple client and server using sockets in C. Both the client and server are running Ubuntu. The server is broadcasting an ad-hoc network that the  however I cannot seem to get the client to connect to the server despite being able to ping it from terminal.

The code I'm using for the server and client are adapted from an online source and are as such:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
char *message;

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("bind failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (new_socket<0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connection accepted");

//Reply to the client
message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));

return 0;
}
```

Client

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>    
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <arpa/inet.h> 

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *message;

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected\n");

//Send some data
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Data Send\n");

return 0;
}
```

The IP address was obtained by running ifconfig on the terminal of the server and looking at its inet addr value.

Additionally I've also disabled the firewall on both the client and the server by running sudo ufw disable in the terminal. Errno also outputs connection refused.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Double-check the port numbers...

Comment: I tried changing both port numbers to 8888 but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Can you please show the _exact_ error? Use e.g. `perror` or `strerror` to print it. Also, please clarify the network setup you have. Are both client and server on the same computer? Different computers? How are they connected? Firewalls? Etc.

Comment: Essentially the setup I have is that one computer is broadcasting an wifi ad-hoc network as another computer joins the network to attempt to connect to the server. The exact error I'm getting when I use strerror is "Connection Refused". Like I mentioned in the question I have disabled the firewall.

Also I'm not sure if this helps but pinging the address works, however trying to connect to the listening port using telnet does not.

Comment: @user1721182 use *netcat* check if your server is set up correctly: `netcat -vz 192.168.0.1 8888`.

Answer (score 3):

Your server listens to port 8888 and client tries to connect to port 80, both `server.sin_port = htons( x );` must use the same port number.

Comment: I've tried doing this and the same error still occurs. Additionally pinging the address works, however trying to connect to the listening port using telnet does not work either.

Comment: @user1721182 I did try to compile and run your code - and I can assure you it works (after changing both port numbers to 8888). So if you still cannot get it working, the problem must be in your network, firewall, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly using `inet_addr("192.168.0.1")`;

use

```
struct sockaddr_in6 ser_address;
inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.0.1",&ser_address.sin.addr);
```

Note: We cannot use presentation style address in the codes when passing it to socket functions